# Postgres - Permissões dentro da função

Tags: postgresql

Estou montando um sistema na qual o usuário terão um acesso bem limitado, apenas visualizar e executar determinadas funções especificas.

### Cenário (com usuário root)

Possui três tabelas :

- Person
- Device
- Access

E três 4 funções :

- sync_person()
- sync_device()
- sync_access()
- sync_access_user()

#### Desejado (com usuário normal)

O usuário só deve poder :

- table person - Consultar (`SELECT`)
- sync_person() - Executar
- sync_device() - Executar
- sync_access_user() - Executar

### Problema

As funções estão gerando erro de permissão para as execuções internas.

#### Cenário hipotético (Criado por root)

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    name    VARCHAR
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(
    name    VARCHAR
) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $func$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test VALUES (name);
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION test(VARCHAR) TO normal_user;
```

#### Execução (Usuário normal)

```
SELECT test('Temwifi');

ERROR: permission denied for relation test
SQL state: 42501
Context: SQL statement "INSERT INTO test VALUES (name)"
PL/pgSQL function test(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
```

### Questão

- Como permitir que o usuário normal execute a função, sem liberar acesso direto aos recursos necessários? Ex.: `INSERT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito adicionando o parâmetro `SECURITY DEFINER` na função, como [explica na documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

> A função é executada com os privilégios do usuário que a criou.

Assim você pode conceder o privilegio a um usuário de executar esta função, sem necessariamente ele ter privilégios aos recursos necessários.

#### Adendo

A documentação ainda alerta para ter cuidado ao realizar essa operação, pois um usuário mal intencionado pode se aproveitar de algum privilegio presente desta função.